# Dict TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I have an AWS Lambda python function calling SecretsManager to get a secret value. I get the SecretString but when I try to access the elements I get a

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Please see my code below:

```
presigned_url_user_credentials = sm_client.get_secret_value(SecretId='Lambda_IAMUser')['SecretString']
print(presigned_url_user_credentials)
print(presigned_url_user_credentials["Access_key"])
```

The SecretsString return the follow dict

```json
{"Access_key":"xxxxxxxxxx","Secret_key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Comment: I doubt that `print(type(presigned_url_user_credentials))` says `dict`. You wouldn't get this error if it did, unless the error is happening somewhere else.

Comment: correct ran in terminal by copying the output of print(type(presigned_url_user_credentials)) and assigning it to a value and printing that value type

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why would you need to copy something like `dict` or `string` to a variable instead of just looking at it?

Comment: Please add the full traceback to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The SecretString in the response returns the string value.
You should be converting it to JSON from string like below -

```
presigned_url_user_credentials = sm_client.get_secret_value(SecretId='Lambda_IAMUser')['SecretString']
print(json.loads(presigned_url_user_credentials)["Access_key"])
```